# Spherical Mean of Schwartz Function Decreases Rapidly - Stein, Shakarchi, Fourier Analysis.

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, spherical-coordinates, schwartz-space

I'm studying Stein and Shakarchi's Fourier Analysis book, and I'm stumped on page. 189, where it talks about the spherical mean of a function.

The book defines the **spherical mean** of a complex-valued function $f$ over a sphere of center $x$ and radius $t$ as such:

$$M_t(f)(x) = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{S^2} f(x-t\gamma) d\sigma(\gamma),$$

where $\gamma \in S^2$ and $\sigma(\gamma)$ is the "surface element" or "spherical measure" of $S^2$.

Now I wish to prove that, given $f \in \mathbf{S}(\mathbb{R}^3)$, where $\mathbf{S}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ denotes the Schwartz functions on $\mathbb{R}^3$, the spherical mean $M_t(f)(x)$ is also Schwartz.

Here is what Stein writes:

To show that $M_t(f)$ is rapidly decreasing, start with the inequality $|f(x)| \leq A_N/(1+|x|^N)$, which holds for every fixed $N\geq 0$. As a simple consequence, whenever $t$ is fixed, we have
$$|f(x-\gamma t)| \leq A_N' / (1 + |x|^N) \text{  for all }\gamma \in S^2.$$
To see this consider separately the cases when $|x|\leq 2|t|$ and $|x|>2|t|$.

I think I've proven the second case, as such:

If $|x|>2t$ notice that $||x|-|t||> |x|/2.$
Hence
$$|f(x-t\gamma)| \leq \frac{A_N}{1+|x-t\gamma|^N} \leq \frac{A_N}{1 + ||x|-|t||^N} \leq \frac{A_N}{1+|x/2|^N} \leq \frac{2^N A_N}{1 + |x|^N}.$$

But I'm absolutely stumped on the first case; I have no idea how to proceed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you can argue by the fact that the function $|f(x-t\gamma)|(1+|x|^N)$ is continuous on the compact $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3 : |x|\leq 2|t|\}$ that it attains a maximum $A_N$. Then, by definition $|f(x-t\gamma)|\leq A_N/(1+|x|^N).$

Comment: I chose poorly to denote the maximum by $A_N$, since $A_N$ was already used for another variable, I meant $M_N$, for some $M_N>0$.

Comment: @MathNewbie Oh, never thought about it in that way. Thanks for the comment.